# moreNavigationController is always nil in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to customize the title of my More button in my `UITabBarController` as I'm doing the app in another language. I subclassed `UITabBarController` to be able to access the `tabBarController` property. Unfortunately, it's always `nil` whether I put it in `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear(_)`. Any thoughts on how I can edit it?

```
import UIKit

class ControllerVC: UITabBarController {

    let uiManager = UIManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if let tabBarItem = tabBarController?.moreNavigationController.tabBarItem {
            let deselectedImage = tabBarItem.image
            let selectedImage = tabBarItem.selectedImage
            tabBarController!.moreNavigationController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "بیشتر", image: deselectedImage, selectedImage: selectedImage)
        } else {
            uiManager.showActivityIndicator(self)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @DivyeshGondaliya That's not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with `moreNavigationController`. The problem is with `tabBarController`. Your class is a `UITabBarController`. A tab bar controller's `tabBarController` property is always `nil`.

Just do:

```
let tabBarItem = moreNavigationController.tabBarItem
let deselectedImage = tabBarItem.image
let selectedImage = tabBarItem.selectedImage
moreNavigationController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "بیشتر", image: deselectedImage, selectedImage: selectedImage)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now it goes inside the if statement. The only problem is that the changes I made don't take effect. I write `moreNavigationController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "بیشتر", image: deselectedImage, selectedImage: selectedImage)` but it doesn't work. The plain simple More button with the label 'More' is shown.

Comment: That's a separate issue from your original question. But it may simply be that you can't change the tab of the "more" controller. It should change automatically if your app is properly localized.